# Use monobehaviour from asmdef generated assembly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We would like to distribute our project with assembly files instead of .cs scripts.
We thought that this would be easy thanks to assembly definition files, as unity is creating assembly files for the scripts they refer to anyway.
It turns out that when removing the .cs files and putting the assemblies, we ran into a problem :
The `monobehaviors` defined in the assemblies (so previously in our scripts) can't be added manually to a scene :

> "Can't add script component xxx because the script class cannot be found"

While if we add the component through script (i.e. `AddComponent`) it works.

I'm using Unity 2017.3.f1 to generate the assembly files

Is there a trick to make this work ? or should I try to generate the assemblies using another approach ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Please update with an answer if you did.

Comment: @MichaelHouse how are you building said assemblies?

Comment: @Ron I'm using Unity's `AssemblyBuilder` class. Your answer doesn't show your build process.

Comment: I just let Unity detect code change, compile it and copy it from the output folder

Comment: The problem I guess is that Unity expects every `MonoBehaviour` component to be an individual script file with matching name...

Answer (score 2):

OP here.

Short answer is : don't keep both asmdef and assembly files. Remove the asmdef file if you replace the scripts with the generated assembly

What I ended up doing is the roughly following (this was for CI purpose):
First, we need to make sure Unity compiles the assembly file. So I have a GenerateAssemblies.cs file in an Editor folder that can be executed from command line:

GenerateAssemblies.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Compilation;
using UnityEngine;


[InitializeOnLoad]
public static class GenerateAssemblies
{
    private static string BATCH_MODE_PARAM = "-batchmode";
    private const string REPLACE_ASSEMBLY_PARAM = "-replaceassembly";

    static GenerateAssemblies()
    {
        List<String> args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().ToList();

        if (args.Any(arg => arg.ToLower().Equals(BATCH_MODE_PARAM)))
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("GenerateAssemblies will try to parse the command line to replace assemblies.\n" +
               "\t Use {0} \"assemblyname\" for every assembly you wish to replace"
               , REPLACE_ASSEMBLY_PARAM);
        }

        if (args.Any(arg => arg.ToLower().Equals(REPLACE_ASSEMBLY_PARAM))) // is a replacement requested ?
        {
            int lastIndex = 0;
            while (lastIndex != -1)
            {
                lastIndex = args.FindIndex(lastIndex, arg => arg.ToLower().Equals(REPLACE_ASSEMBLY_PARAM));
                if (lastIndex >= 0 && lastIndex + 1 < args.Count)
                {
                    string assemblyToReplace = args[lastIndex + 1];
                    if (!assemblyToReplace.EndsWith(ReplaceAssemblies.ASSEMBLY_EXTENSION))
                        assemblyToReplace = assemblyToReplace + ReplaceAssemblies.ASSEMBLY_EXTENSION;
                    ReplaceAssemblies.instance.AddAssemblyFileToReplace(assemblyToReplace);
                    Debug.LogFormat("Added assembly {0} to the list of assemblies to replace.", assemblyToReplace);
                    lastIndex++;
                }
            }
            CompilationPipeline.assemblyCompilationFinished += ReplaceAssemblies.instance.ReplaceAssembly; /* This serves as callback after Unity as compiled an assembly */

            Debug.Log("Forcing recompilation of all scripts");
            // to force recompilation
            PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(BuildTargetGroup.Standalone, PlayerSettings.GetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(BuildTargetGroup.Standalone) + ";DUMMY_SYMBOL");
            AssetDatabase.Refresh(ImportAssetOptions.ForceUpdate);
        }
    }

}
```

Then I have a ReplaceAssemblies.cs file in an editor folder that will :

1. find the assembly file correpsonding to the asmdef file
2. save the guid/classes correspondance of the script files
3. move the script files in a temporary folder
4. move the assembly in the same folder as the asmdef file
5. move the asmdef to a temporary folder
6. Replace the Guid and File ID values for each script in the assembly (to avoid breaking references in scenes and prefabs)

ReplaceAssemblies.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Compilation;
using UnityEngine;

public class ReplaceAssemblies : ScriptableSingleton<ReplaceAssemblies>
{

    public static string ASSEMBLY_EXTENSION = ".dll";
    public static string ASSEMBLY_DEFINITION_EXTENSION = ".asmdef";

    [SerializeField]
    private List<String> assembliesFilesToReplace = new List<string>();

    [SerializeField]
    private List<string> pathsOfAssemblyFilesInAssetFolder = new List<string>();
    [SerializeField]
    private List<string> pathsOfAssemblyFilesCreatedByUnity = new List<string>();

    [SerializeField]
    private string tempSourceFilePath;

    private static readonly string[] fileListPath = { "*.prefab", "*.unity", "*.asset" };


    public string TempSourceFilePath
    {
        get
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tempSourceFilePath))
            {
                tempSourceFilePath = FileUtil.GetUniqueTempPathInProject();
            }

            return tempSourceFilePath;
        }
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        Debug.Log("temp dir : " + TempSourceFilePath);
    }

    public void ReplaceAssembly(string assemblyPath, CompilerMessage[] messages)
    {
        string assemblyFileName = assembliesFilesToReplace.Find(assembly => assemblyPath.EndsWith(assembly));
        // is this one of the assemblies we want to replace ?
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(assemblyFileName))
        {
            string[] assemblyDefinitionFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(".", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(assemblyFileName) + ASSEMBLY_DEFINITION_EXTENSION, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            if (assemblyDefinitionFilePaths.Length > 0)
            {
                string assemblyDefinitionFilePath = assemblyDefinitionFilePaths[0];
                ReplaceAssembly(assemblyDefinitionFilePath);
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddAssemblyFileToReplace(string assemblyFile)
    {
        assembliesFilesToReplace.Add(assemblyFile);
    }

    private void ReplaceAssembly(string assemblyDefinitionFilePath)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("Replacing scripts for assembly definition file {0}", assemblyDefinitionFilePath);
        string asmdefDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyDefinitionFilePath);
        string assemblyName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(assemblyDefinitionFilePath);
        Assembly assemblyToReplace = CompilationPipeline.GetAssemblies().ToList().Find(assembly => assembly.name.ToLower().Equals(assemblyName.ToLower()));
        string assemblyPath = assemblyToReplace.outputPath;
        string assemblyFileName = Path.GetFileName(assemblyPath);
        string[] assemblyFilePathInAssets = Directory.GetFiles("./Assets", assemblyFileName, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        // save the guid/classname correspondance of the scripts that we will remove
        Dictionary<string, string> oldGUIDToClassNameMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (assemblyFilePathInAssets.Length <= 0)
        {
            // Move all script files outside the asset folder
            foreach (string sourceFile in assemblyToReplace.sourceFiles)
            {
                string tempScriptPath = Path.Combine(TempSourceFilePath, sourceFile);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(tempScriptPath));
                if (!File.Exists(sourceFile))
                    Debug.LogErrorFormat("File {0} does not exist while the assembly {1} references it.", sourceFile, assemblyToReplace.name);
                Debug.Log("will move " + sourceFile + " to " + tempScriptPath);
                // save the guid of the file because we may need to replace it later
                MonoScript monoScript = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<MonoScript>(sourceFile);
                if (monoScript != null && monoScript.GetClass() != null)
                    oldGUIDToClassNameMap.Add(AssetDatabase.AssetPathToGUID(sourceFile), monoScript.GetClass().FullName);
                FileUtil.MoveFileOrDirectory(sourceFile, tempScriptPath);
            }

            Debug.Log("Map of GUID/Class : \n" + String.Join("\n", oldGUIDToClassNameMap.Select(pair => pair.Key + " : " + pair.Value).ToArray()));

            string finalAssemblyPath = Path.Combine(asmdefDirectory, assemblyFileName);
            Debug.Log("will move " + assemblyPath + " to " + finalAssemblyPath);
            FileUtil.MoveFileOrDirectory(assemblyPath, finalAssemblyPath);
            string tempAsmdefPath = Path.Combine(TempSourceFilePath, Path.GetFileName(assemblyDefinitionFilePath));
            Debug.Log("will move " + assemblyDefinitionFilePath + " to " + tempAsmdefPath);
            FileUtil.MoveFileOrDirectory(assemblyDefinitionFilePath, tempAsmdefPath);
            // Rename the asmdef meta file to the dll meta file so that the dll guid stays the same
            FileUtil.MoveFileOrDirectory(assemblyDefinitionFilePath + ".meta", finalAssemblyPath + ".meta");
            pathsOfAssemblyFilesInAssetFolder.Add(finalAssemblyPath);
            pathsOfAssemblyFilesCreatedByUnity.Add(assemblyPath);


            // We need to refresh before accessing the assets in the new assembly
            AssetDatabase.Refresh();


            // We need to remove .\ when using LoadAsslAssetsAtPath
            string cleanFinalAssemblyPath = finalAssemblyPath.Replace(".\\", "");
            var assetsInAssembly = AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath(cleanFinalAssemblyPath);

            // list all components in the assembly file. 
            var assemblyObjects = assetsInAssembly.OfType<MonoScript>().ToArray();

            // save the new GUID and file ID for the MonoScript in the new assembly
            Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, long>> newMonoScriptToIDsMap = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, long>>();
            // for each component, replace the guid and fileID file
            for (var i = 0; i < assemblyObjects.Length; i++)
            {
                long dllFileId;
                string dllGuid = null;
                if (AssetDatabase.TryGetGUIDAndLocalFileIdentifier(assemblyObjects[i], out dllGuid, out dllFileId))
                {
                    string fullClassName = assemblyObjects[i].GetClass().FullName;
                    newMonoScriptToIDsMap.Add(fullClassName, new KeyValuePair<string, long>(dllGuid, dllFileId));
                }
            }

            Debug.Log("Map of Class/GUID:FILEID : \n" + String.Join("\n", newMonoScriptToIDsMap.Select(pair => pair.Key + " : " + pair.Value.Key + " - " + pair.Value.Value).ToArray()));

            ReplaceIdsInAssets(oldGUIDToClassNameMap, newMonoScriptToIDsMap);
        }


        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Already found an assembly file named " + assemblyFileName + " in asset folder");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Replace ids in all asset files using the given maps
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="oldGUIDToClassNameMap">Maps GUID to be replaced => FullClassName</param>
    /// <param name="newMonoScriptToIDsMap">Maps FullClassName => new GUID, new FileID</param>
    private static void ReplaceIdsInAssets(Dictionary<string, string> oldGUIDToClassNameMap, Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, long>> newMonoScriptToIDsMap)
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Report of replaced ids : \n");
        // list all the potential files that might need guid and fileID update
        List<string> fileList = new List<string>();
        foreach (string extension in fileListPath)
        {
            fileList.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(Application.dataPath, extension, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
        }
        foreach (string file in fileList)
        {
            string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

            for (int line = 0; line < fileLines.Length; line++)
            {
                //find all instances of the string "guid: " and grab the next 32 characters as the old GUID
                if (fileLines[line].Contains("guid: "))
                {
                    int index = fileLines[line].IndexOf("guid: ") + 6;
                    string oldGUID = fileLines[line].Substring(index, 32); // GUID has 32 characters.
                    if (oldGUIDToClassNameMap.ContainsKey(oldGUID) && newMonoScriptToIDsMap.ContainsKey(oldGUIDToClassNameMap[oldGUID]))
                    {
                        fileLines[line] = fileLines[line].Replace(oldGUID, newMonoScriptToIDsMap[oldGUIDToClassNameMap[oldGUID]].Key);
                        output.AppendFormat("File {0} : Found GUID {1} of class {2}. Replaced with new GUID {3}.", file, oldGUID, oldGUIDToClassNameMap[oldGUID], newMonoScriptToIDsMap[oldGUIDToClassNameMap[oldGUID]].Key);
                        if (fileLines[line].Contains("fileID: "))
                        {
                            index = fileLines[line].IndexOf("fileID: ") + 8;
                            int index2 = fileLines[line].IndexOf(",", index);
                            string oldFileID = fileLines[line].Substring(index, index2 - index); // GUID has 32 characters.
                            fileLines[line] = fileLines[line].Replace(oldFileID, newMonoScriptToIDsMap[oldGUIDToClassNameMap[oldGUID]].Value.ToString());
                            output.AppendFormat("Replaced fileID {0} with {1}", oldGUID, newMonoScriptToIDsMap[oldGUIDToClassNameMap[oldGUID]].Value.ToString());
                        }
                        output.Append("\n");
                    }
                }
            }
            //Write the lines back to the file
            File.WriteAllLines(file, fileLines);
        }
        Debug.Log(output.ToString());
    }

    [MenuItem("Tools/Replace Assembly")]
    public static void ReplaceAssemblyMenu()
    {
        string assemblyDefinitionFilePath = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel(
            title: "Select Assembly Definition File",
            directory: Application.dataPath,
            extension: ASSEMBLY_DEFINITION_EXTENSION.Substring(1));
        if (assemblyDefinitionFilePath.Length == 0)
            return;

        instance.ReplaceAssembly(assemblyDefinitionFilePath);

    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for coming back and giving a detailed answer. I've awarded the bounty to you.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this issue, and like you, I was using the information provided from asmdef files to provide all the required information (which .cs files, what references, defines, etc) to build an assembly.

I found that the issue was the DLL I was creating had the same name as the asmdef file I was using to provide the information. Even though the asmdef file was no longer being compiled (because all the scripts had been removed to build the DLL), it was still interfering with the project.

So for me, the inconsistency between accessing a script from inside the editor and from inside scripts was because there was a DLL and as asmdef file with the same name in the project.

Giving the compiled DLL a different name or removing the asmdef file was the solution for me.

Comment: Yes the error in question was caused by the presence of both the assembly and asmdef file. I'v put a more detailed answer as to how we replaced asmdef files with dlls automatically in our CI pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Just tested with `Unity 2019.3.0b1`.

Content of test class:

```
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.Test
{
    public class TestBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
    {
        void Start()
        {
            Debug.Log(Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType()));
        }
    }
}
```

**First project with source code and assembly definition file**

[image: First project with source code and assembly definition file]

**Second project with the generated DLL, working as expected**

[image: Second project with the generated DLL, working as expected]

Answer (score 0):

As far as i'm concerned, the use of `asmdef` merely forces unity3d to compile your scripts into separate assemblies that are then referenced by your project.
Actually, it creates projects in your unity solution that contain your `.cs` files and each of these projects is compiled into its own output assembly.

The error you are seeing might be related to assembly caching.
I've had that error a few months ago and it was due to an outdated assembly still being cached.
As a result, `unity3d editor` kinda hiccuped when loading the project and therefore could not load the specific assembly.
I fixed it by deleting the directories `Library`, `obj` and `Temp` and then reloaded the *unity3d project*.

To get rid of that for good, we have moved away from `asmdef` and `.cs` files inside our unity projects once and for all.
All our scripts have been extracted to separate projects that are never touched by unity3d.
Every project references `UnityEngine.dll` and/or `UnityEditor.dll` (for Editor assemblies) depending on which `unity3d types` it may require.
The projects are built locally using `Visual Studio` or server side in our `CI pipeline`.
Output is copied manually into the assets directory of a unity project where it is then loaded from within `unity3d editor`.
This last step is a pain admittedly but i have yet to find time to streamline this process some more.

**This approach has a few benefits**

- We are in control of our code in one single repository.
  There is only one single point of truth and every developer commits changes onto the same code base.
  There are no copies of `.cs` files across any number of unity projects that consume our types.
- There is no need to figure out merge conflicts from updating a `unitypackage` where there have been deletions.
- Unit tests can be done server side (`CI pipeline`) without the need of some docker image with unity3d on top (ofc there are restrictions on how much you can test *without the entire unity3d environment running*).
- We create our own `NuGet` packages that can be referenced in projects (`vcproj`, *not unity projects!*).
- Types deriving from `MonoBehaviour` can be added to `GameObjects` via code or via `unity3d editor`.
  You also get to explore loaded assemblies inside your `unity3d editor` project view by clicking on the arrow of an assembly which will expand to show the list of contained relevant types.

**Let's talk about downsides**

One example is that we use SteamVR for interacting with controls.
The SteamVR plugin for unity3d is released through `unity's asset store` and annoyingly it contains script files and resources but *no assemblies*.
This goes for pretty much all assets in the store by the way.
Since we can't build against code, we have to go through the trouble of compiling SteamVR once and then copy the output assembly somewhere else.

This is not just as tedious as a task can be, it also has some limitations of its own which i get to later.
Anyway, this lets us reference a compiled asset with our own code so we get to use asset specific types like `SteamVR_Action` in our code without having to use `unity3d editor` and script files in unity projects (or reflection which would be even worse).

Limitations of compiled assets like this are two fold.
For once, it is horribly inefficient to get there in the first place.
On the other hand, you'll only have to do that once for every version of an asset.
Once that's done, make it a private `NuGet` package and you're golden.

The other limitation is the way how unity3d approaches dependency injection.
Actually i'm not entirely sure what it really is they try to do but here goes.
Unity3d wants you to only ever reference assemblies from within `../UnityInstallDirectory/Editor/Data/Managed/`.

In a perfect world, your own assemblies reference that big gunky `UnityEngine.dll` in this directory and once loaded by `unity3d editor` everything works as expected.
When you compile a unity project from within `unity3d editor` however, the resulting assembly references all the assemblies from within `../UnityInstallDirectory/Editor/Data/Managed/UnityEngine/` which contains a very small version of `UnityEngine.dll` which in turn acts as a type forwarder to all the other sub modules.

Not such a perfect world now is it?
Your previously compiled asset requires the type `MonoBehaviour` to sit in an assembly called `UnityEngine.CoreModule.dll`.
Your own project however expects it to sit in `UnityEngine.dll` since you're a good fellow and follow the rules.

This is just asking for trouble and to get around this problem we are now directly referencing all the managed sub modules from within `../UnityInstallDirectory/Editor/Data/Managed/UnityEngine/`.
We also ignore `unity3d editor` moaning about how we are doing it wrong.

**tl;dr**

By doing all from above and leaving `asmdef` and `.cs` files out of the equation we are able to build, unit test and pack our logic and types into assemblies.
We are also able to keep a clean code base that can be easily maintained and extended without dozens of copies of the same code in multiple locations and/or repositories.

Why unity3d does things the way they do, i'll never understand.
I do know there is a thing called [Building from HEAD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tISy7EJQPzI) but since the entirety of the .net ecosystem is using the binary format to share content in the form of referable assemblies, why would you want to do things differently?
This is a topic for another day though.

If you made it all the way through this post, i sincerely hope it is helping you fix your problem at hand.
In case i misinterpreted your question ... sorry :-)

Unity3d is weird ...